# Showing a veil/spinner when sorting a table column using ControllerAs syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

In an app I am working on, we have one view that has a table, that can potentially load thousands of records (by default it shows 100 at a time, but lazy-loads in chunks of 100 records.)  In Angular 1, this takes some time, so I'm working on figuring out how to present a loading spinner whenever someone attempts to sort all of this information.

I was doing some basic research and stumbled upon [this StackOverflow answer back in 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354782/showing-a-loader-widget-on-angularjs-sort-feature-using-orderby) that shows it is in fact possible to do this sort of thing.  The problem is, Angular has matured/changed quite a bit in two years.

I forked a Plunker that was used in that question - [this is that forked plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/zLp05kk1/) - yet altering the sort order by changing the dropdown does not seem to be actually doing anything.  I wrote events that should show an alert stating what is happening with the sort process, and throwing up the "veil" that informs the user that the load process is going on.

For those who don't like looking at plunkers, here's the relevant code:

**View:**

```
<div ng-controller="ContactListCtrl as vm">

    <h1>AngularJS Sorting Example</h1>

    <select ng-model="vm.sortReverse" ng-change="vm.parseSortDirection()">
        <option value="false">Surname (A-Z)</option>
        <option value="true">Surname (Z-A)</option>
    </select>
    <table class="contacts">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Telephone</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="contact in vm.contacts | orderBy:vm.sortingOrder:vm.sortReverse" 
        repeat-start="vm.onSortStart()"
        repeat-done="vm.onSortDone()" >
            <td ng-class-even="'even'">{{contact.name}}, {{contact.surname}}</td>
            <td ng-class-even="'even'">{{contact.telephone}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="veil" ng-show="vm.isLoading"></div>
    <div id="feedLoading" ng-show="vm.isLoading">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

app.controller('ContactListCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $filter) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.sortingOrder = 'name';

    vm.sortorder = 'surname';
    vm.contacts = [{
        "name": "Richard",
        "surname": "Stallman",
        "telephone": "1234 98765"
    }, {
        "name": "Donald",
        "surname": "Knuth",
        "telephone": "3456 76543"
    }, {
        "name": "Linus",
        "surname": "Torvalds",
        "telephone": "2345 87654"
    }];

    vm.parseSortDirection = function () {
        vm.sortReverse = vm.sortReverse.toLowerCase() == "true";
    };

    vm.onSortStart = function () {
        alert('Sort started...');
        $scope.isLoading = true;
    }

    $scope.onSortDone = function (value) {
        alert('Sort complete.');
        $scope.isLoading = false;
    }

    vm.loadFeed = function(url) {       
        $scope.isLoading = true;        
    }

    vm.loadFeed();
});

app.directive('repeatStart', function () {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if(scope.$first) {
            scope.$eval(attrs.repeatStart);
        }
    };
});

app.directive('repeatDone', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) {
            scope.$eval(attrs.repeatDone);
        }
    }
});
```

**Question:** Using ControllerAs syntax, in what way can I cause a column sort on a table controlled by an AngularJS controller, to execute code designed to inform the user that a sort is ongoing?

Comment: You could simplify by just adding a row with ng-show where you just trigger a loading boolean (kind of like isLoading)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow.

Comment: <tr ng-show="isLoading">Loading...</tr>

Comment: While that was a good suggestion, it had no effect.  The reason this is the case, is that altering the 'reverse' flag happens instantaneously, but the `orderBy` setup instead sorts as soon as it registers a digest where the `orderBy` variable has changed.  This is why I'm trying to set hooks into the sort process itself, so that I can arbitrarily execute code when a sort starts, and ends.